# JOGL- create texture invalid

Tags: java, jogl

Can anyone please tell me why I encounter this error in JOGL and how I can fix this? I have enabled textures before but it fails only this one time. I tried clearing the buffer but nada.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.media.opengl.GLException: Create texture ID invalid: texID 0, glerr 0x0
at com.jogamp.opengl.util.texture.Texture.validateTexID(Texture.java:1090)
at com.jogamp.opengl.util.texture.Texture.updateImage(Texture.java:457)
at com.jogamp.opengl.util.texture.Texture.updateImage(Texture.java:434)
at com.jogamp.opengl.util.texture.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:203)
at com.jogamp.opengl.util.texture.TextureIO.newTexture(TextureIO.java:448)
at com.jogamp.opengl.util.texture.TextureIO.newTexture(TextureIO.java:499)
at Object1.createTexture1(Object1.java:42)
```

I am trying to create a texture to map to a sweep Object using the following code snippet:

```
Texture createTexture(String fname) 
    {

        try {
            InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(fname);
            myTexture = TextureIO.newTexture( stream, true, "jpg" );  //creates a  texture
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        myTexture.setTexParameteri(JOGL.gl, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                GL2.GL_LINEAR);   //sets properties for the texture

        return myTexture;

    }

I have designed my redraw as:

    JOGL.gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    myTexture = createTexture("Sunrise.jpg");

    myTexture.enable(JOGL.gl);

    myTexture.bind(JOGL.gl); 

    JOGL.gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);// followed by drawing a quad and mapping the texture to it
```